# When is the matrix $X^t A X$ invertible, with $A$ invertible.

Tags: matrices

I was wondering what are the conditions on $X$ such that the product $X^tAX$ is invertible, with $X$ an $n\times m$ matrix and $A$ an $n\times n$ invertible matrix.

Specifically I am interested in know if $X^tAX$ is invertible when $X$ if of full rank, and if $X^tAX$ is necessarily not invertible when if X is not of full rank.

I am a little rusty in this subject, so I don't know how to begin with a possible proof.

Comment: one necessary condition is $m\le n$

Comment: another condition is $X$ is of rank$=m$

Comment: you can show that these two conditions suffice

Comment: To prove @Ben statement, Its useful to use the SVD decomposition on X. It reduces your problem to only considering X diagonal, where the number of non-zero coefficients is the rank, then the conditions appear naturally. It would be also useful to think in terms of injectivity/surjectivity.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Note that for invertibility of $B:= X^T AX$, we need ${\rm ker}\
X =\{0 \}$

(2) Assume that $B$ is invertible Let **V:=range X** Then $AV=
V$ :

Proof : If not, there exists $v=Xv'\neq 0\in V$ s.t. $AV\perp v$ So
$$ 0=( AV,v)=(AV, Xv')=(X^T AX {\bf R}^m,v') $$
It is a contradiction since $B$ is invertible

(3) $X^TAX$ is invertible iff ${\rm ker}\ X = \{ 0 \} $ and **AV=V**

Proof : $\Rightarrow$ We already showed

$\Leftarrow$ For any $y\in {\rm R}^m$, then $$ Xy\in V\Rightarrow
\exists x\ {\rm s.t.}\ A(Xx)=Xy $$

That is $X^TAXx=y$ has a unique solution. Hence $B$ is invertible.